gRPC and Consul conflict issue with latest updated versions
When i'm tring to create and Adopting Service Discovery with Consul, for my golang microservice  projects, consul and grpc conflicts with each other. When it removed grpc issue solved easyliy, but i cannot use updated versions, whay that happens.? does consul have the grpc dependencies.? to cause that.?
error while importing google.golang.org/grpc/status: ambiguous import: found package google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status in multiple modules:
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20230410155749-daa745c078e1 (/home/pasan/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/genproto@v0.0.0-20230410155749-daa745c078e1/googleapis/rpc/status)
    google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc v0.0.0-20240711142825-46eb208f015d (/home/pasan/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc@v0.0.0-20240711142825-46eb208f015d/status)compiler
google.golang.org/grpc
This module is necessary because google.golang.org/grpc is imported in common/api.

i'm tring to add an import as an --
consul "github.com/hashicorp/consul/api"

to create ne registory --
type Registry struct{
    client *consul.Client
}

func NewRegistory(addr, serviceName string)  (*Registry, error) {
    config := consul.DefaultConfig()
    config.Address = addr
    client, err := consul.NewClient(config)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &Registry{client}, nil
}

its created using the instructions that have said in
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pU_lDwHs9IY
but when its imported auto matically register is unable to create and, when i add the specific package to import consul, its conflicts with grpc

I'm unable to repro your issue with the code you provide with Go 1.22. Please update your question so that the code provides a minimal repro of the issue you observe.

i have the same issue in my project that use GRPC (no any consul references). It appeared when I added go.work file to the project and gone when I deleted it.

take a look here. this is a PR from in the response to the similar issue
question: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/2613
pr: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/pull/2614/files#diff-a20b1b3b4b2bca5bef2b853a6e3f19def513381f9c7ee68d6979f0435c885dcfR148
